# What is causing this query to freeze when I add a constraint?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2019 - I have a query:

```
SELECT
    h.ItemType, h.ItemNum, h.Color, h.Cond, pg.*
FROM
    Inventory_Item_History_Summary h
LEFT JOIN 
    Price_Overrides po ON po.ItemType LIKE h.ItemType + '%' 
                       AND po.ItemNum = h.ItemNum  
                       AND po.ColorID = h.Color 
                       AND po.Cond = h.Cond
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         maxdate = MAX(PriceDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNo, ItemType, Color, Cond) 
     FROM 
         [Price_Guide]) AS pg ON pg.PriceDate = pg.Maxdate 
                              AND pg.ItemType LIKE h.ItemType + '%' 
                              AND pg.ItemNo = h.ItemNum 
                              AND pg.Cond = h.Cond 
                              AND pg.Color = h.Color
WHERE 
    po.Price IS NULL 
    AND pg.ItemNo IS NULL
```

If I run it *without* the `pg.ItemNo IS NULL` constraint, it takes less than a second to return 14,212 rows. I ran it *with* that constraint and it takes 6.5 minutes to complete with 3041 records returned.

If I dump the result set without the ItemNo is null constraint into Excel and filter it, I find out in a half a second that there are 3041 records where ItemNo is null.

What could cause SQL Server to hang on such a simple filter in the `Where` clause, especially when it returns the full result set so quickly?

Note: I'm not using `EXISTS` because ultimately my `WHERE` clause should read:

```
WHERE po.Price IS NULL 
  AND (pg.ItemNo IS NULL OR pg.maxdate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 30)
```

meaning that I want the `Price_Guide` data returned if maxdate is too old. I posted the simplified version above because that's where I narrowed down the hang issue to.

EDIT: See below for a partial comparison of the execution plans. You can see that in the execution with ItemNo is null, the filter says "41300072 of 291" whereas in the execution without the filter says "2906 of 291". Also oddly the fast run has a Hash Map at the end where the slow run has Nested Loops

[image]

Update: I was able to do a rework of the query below that takes 3 seconds - still slow considering the full recordset returns in less than 1. However if anyone can shed light as to why the original got so clogged up I'd love to hear your thoughts.

```
Select h.ItemType, h.ItemNum, h.Color, h.Cond, pg.*
FROM Inventory_Item_History_Summary h
    LEFT JOIN Price_Overrides po on po.ItemType like h.ItemType + '%' and po.ItemNum=h.ItemNum and po.ColorID=h.Color and po.Cond=h.Cond
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT g.*, mpg.maxdate FROM Price_Guide g
                JOIN (SELECT ItemNo, ItemType, Color, Cond, max(PriceDate) as maxdate 
                        FROM Price_Guide GROUP BY ItemNo, ItemType, Color, Cond) mpg
                       on g.ItemNo=mpg.ItemNo and g.ItemType=mpg.ItemType and g.Color=mpg.Color and g.cond=mpg.cond and g.PriceDate=mpg.maxdate) AS pg on pg.ItemType like h.ItemType + '%' AND pg.ItemNo=h.ItemNum and pg.Cond=h.Cond and pg.Color=h.Color
WHERE po.Price IS NULL and (pg.maxdate is null or pg.maxdate<CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-30)
```

Comment: did you compare the execution plan of both query?

Comment: I don't know how to read the execution plan tbh

Comment: Sometimes something as simple as isnull(pg.itemno,0) <> 0 will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

To make sure everything is OK with your server, please execute this (you're not in a production server, right?)

First, rebuild the index on your table:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [Price_Guide] REBUILD
```

Then, flush all execution plan cached on the server (still not in production, right?)

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Then, execute your query with `pg.ItemNo IS NULL`

Do you still have the problem? No, fine.

Yes?   Select both query and hit CTRL-L to get estimated execution plan of both query. Right-click and click on "show execution plan XML".  Then, copy the xml execution plan and paste it on https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/  and share the url.

EDIT: did you perform both command?  I was wondering since there is something weird in the executions plans.

If you take a look at the bottom branch of the fastest one. This is what the execution plan shows, it has estimated 2906 rows to be read and, effectively, it had read 2906

[image]

The second execution show this :  it has estimated to read 2906 rows, but (put you favorite bad word here) it read 41.3 millions rows, that's of lot of rows he did not expected.

[image]

Ok, now, what to do. My guess is to take a look at your indexes and rethinking you query.  To you really need all field from Price_Guide, only a few? Does the clustered index is the only index on the table or others indexes exists? Consider creating an (filtered?) index based on the need of the query.  You need to rework you query to make sure to reduce this.

Comment: Local server - developing a VB.Net app.  Still took 6.5 minutes to complete - here's the slow plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1IPds4zP and the fast plan (without the constraint) is here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1YzKj4Mw

Comment: Yes I did run both commands. I also noticed the 41M records in the snippet I pasted in the original question. What's so puzzling is why does this simply where clause trigger that? I did post a reworked query above

Comment: I don't know how your database  and tables are setup.  but here some hints,  since you have "pg.ItemNo=h.BLItemNum"  in the ON clause of the join and " pg.ItemNo is null" in the where clause, does it make sense to change the "LEFT JOIN" to AN "INNER JOIN", assuming ItemNo is not a nullable column

Comment: and if ItemNo isn't part of the PK, try creating an index with the PK + ItemNo , making it more easy to pick only the interesting rows

Comment: It's looking for records that don't exist in the Price_Override table AND that either don't exist in the Price_Guide table or have a latest price update over 30 days old. ItemNo isn't nullable - it's looking for where the join doesn't exist. But I didn't use NOT EXISTS because I also want to get the price guide data when the price exists but is stale.